# Content Observer for RCS/ "Advanced messaging" type messages

Tags: android, rich-communications-services

As the title reads, I'm trying to figure out a way to also read RCS(Rich Communication Service) type OUTGOING messages.

I currently have SMS outgoing messages logged but when it comes to a conversation that has RCS type messages, I'm not sure how to obtain the Uri.Parse. I've searched on google for the correct method of obtaining this information, but I only see items for SMS/MMS (Which neither of these log RCS messages).

EDIT: I recently bought a S9 + and found out that their "RCS" messages are showing up as "Advanced Messages". But my application still doesn't see these advanced type messages.